# Perform an offline upgrade in post-NT 6 Windows

Tags: windows

Before NT 6.x (Vista/2008). There were a program called winnt which allowed to upgrade a broken windows from DOS (winnt32 was the equivalent for booted systems).  It allowed (while upgrading or downgrading to an another Windows version) to restore the system to a workable state while keeping files and installed programs.

However, since kernel 6.x, the installation method changed. The installer OS featured the Win32 subsystem and the method switched to applying ghost-like images.
The option for upgrading the system turned to a message telling the target system must be booted in order to perform upgrading.
The point is it's still technically possible to do what the old way was doing in the past. But probably without using Microsoft tools.  It’s the matter of understanding what the giant black box called Windows installer is exactly doing.

So what is the way to do what was easy in the past ?

Comment: I’m sure peoples here do remember things like [this](http://www.guidebookgallery.org/pics/gui/installation/licence/winnt40.png) or [this](http://www.operating-system.org/betriebssystem/bsgfx/microsoft/winnt4/winnt40-scr-04.png). The upgrade feature even allowed to convert a freshly installed xp system to a win2k one.

Comment: I've replaced non-Latin characters in your post. Is your keyboard layout preventing you from typing upper-case characters?

Comment: Vista is NT 6.x by the way.....

Comment: You need to define what an offline upgrade is exactly

Comment: @Ramhound: Upgrading without booting into the existing Windows installation.

Comment: @Moab but it is still possible to do what the old way was doing. And the process isn't technially that different from an online upgrade. However, I agree the required tools might need to be created from scratch.

Comment: @Ramhound It seems you aren't understanding. how it works. In both online and offline scenario, it is the matter of deleting or replacing certain files and replacing HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ *(+ all other Microsoft installed software keys like edge or media player)* HKLM\System. You can try to add files to some folder and see those which are kept and those which are deleted after an upgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound though I agree it is far deartier than Unix where you are sure you won't perform kernel crash by modifying userland configuration. Thanks to a better separation between kernel userland, and user configuration, upgrading is always as simple as performing a simple file copy. *(I know this is off topic, but it is in those times I whish getting direct12 could be so simple, sighh)*

Comment: @user2284570 - I fully understand how an installation of Windows is upgraded to the diferent version.  You don't need to explain how it works to me.  Just worry about using proper terminology in this question.